# Figuring which thread is working on which scenario

Tags: karate

Was wondering if there is a convenient way to know which thread is running what scenario or at least when it starts working on it? I would like to be able to see this in the output of the karate-netty.

Like(in my imaginary perfect world):
`21:43:42.790 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] INFO  com.intuit.karate - >> begin scenario: Test1`

**If above is not possible**:
Judging from the logs I cant really figure it for sure. What I figured as a workaround is adding `* print "testing xyz"` at the top of every scenario works for me, now I would like to have my code pretty as well still, so I was wondering if there is a way for me to add something to say `karate-config.js` that would make each scenario print its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this hack in the `Background`

```
* configure responseHeaders = function(){ karate.log('thread:', java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
```

P.S. why !?

Comment: Im working on wrapper for karate function, you get the rest :)

Comment: Will d for sure, just want to test it out first, that will happen in few hours from here :)

Comment: is there a way to print scenario running as well? Or at least file if scenario name is not accesable. With solution you posted above I get `15:40:03.324 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] INFO  com.intuit.karate - thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2 ` which I dont find helpful as it doesent tell me scenario I ran.

Comment: sorry the best I can do is the `uri`: `* configure responseHeaders = function(){ karate.log('thread:', java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName(), karate.get('requestUri')) }`

Comment: I see, hmm, ah well might just go on adding print statement after every scenario, this answer is correct enough I guess, ty

Comment: @DusanGligoric lol, you seem to have karate confused with a full-blown app server  or servlet-engine :P what on earth are you trying to do

Comment: nothing special just create wrapper as I find 5k new lines in my terminal each time I run it amazingly eye stabbing :joy: also I have seeding function which when fails > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692481/when-karate-config-js-fails-it-prints-error-for-each-feature this happens, I could fix that with wrapper as well :)

Comment: basically fancy up the output and fix my tty pain